# How to store image into PostgreSQL using Prisma 2 and NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, prisma

Good day everyone, i was looking for a similar that i can refer to, but sadly i wasn't found yet until now. Hope someone would give me some guidances on it...

I'm using filepond to send the api request, and use the prisma 2 client to store it

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's usually a good practice to store Images in a Blob Storage and images should not directly be stored in the database, so you can use something like [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) or [Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/) to store the image and store the Image's S3 Bucket Path in your PostgreSQL Database.

Here's a working [example](https://mediajams.dev/post/upload-and-display-images-using-prisma) of how you could achieve it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! i was solved it by using cloudinary api and store the image url to postgresql

Comment: Amazing! Glad you were able to solve it

Comment: Why is this answer accepted, it does not answer the question, merely gives a good practice

Comment: Yeah, I'm specifically looking for a way to handle this on premise, without a cloud involved.