# How to store images to a postgreSQL database using Prisma?

Tags: node.js, typescript, prisma

I searched around and couldn't find any clear answer. On Java I created a class like this:

```
@Entity
public class Entity {
    ...
    @Lob
    private byte[] image;
}
```

And later saved a MultipartFile as a byte array using the `.getBytes()` method.
How can I do the same on the Prisma schema?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store image into PostgreSQL using Prisma 2 and NodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71554571/how-to-store-image-into-postgresql-using-prisma-2-and-nodejs)

Comment: no, I want to save the images locally without a cloud storage / bucket even though it says it's not a good practice.